# Why doesnt the adding of strings work for the first two rows in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to add two strings from different columns in one Table.
The shown code works properly for every row **except the first two**

e.g. how it should look like and work

```
a | b => ab
c | d => cd
e | f => ef
```

e.g. what it does at the moment

```
a|b => a
c|d => c
e|f => ef
g|h => gh
i|j => ij
```

I have tried the following queries, none of them work properly

Is there a weird MS Access thing going on? Or is there a mistake in my query?

```
SELECT (([Full_Name] + " ") + [Wohnort] ) AS Test
FROM Mitarbeiter;

SELECT ([Full_Name] + Wohnort) AS Test
FROM Mitarbeiter;

SELECT (([Full_Name] + " ") + Wohnort) AS Test
FROM Mitarbeiter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT ([Full_Name] + " ") & [Wohnort] AS Test
FROM Mitarbeiter;
```

or:

```
SELECT [Full_Name] & (" " + [Wohnort]) AS Test
FROM Mitarbeiter;
```

The purpose of using `+` is to chop the space if `Full Name` is *Null*

Comment: Just to clarify: `NULL + " " = NULL` , `NULL & " " = " "`

Comment: still doesnt work properly. It just ignores the String in "Wohnort" for the first to rows. 

e.g. https://postimg.cc/mc8VG9c3

Comment: _It just ignores the String in "Wohnort" for the first to rows._ It can't. So, either your table is corrupt or something else is going on.

Comment: ok thanks for you help.

probably some weird things happening. Its working fine with other tables

Comment: EDIT: Table was corrupt :-/

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your syntax.  The string concatenation operator in MS Access is `&`, not `+`.  And you might want to take `NULL` values into account:

```
SELECT NZ([Full_Name], "") & NZ(" " & [Wohnort], "") AS Test
```

Comment: still doesnt work properly. It just ignores the String in "Wohnort" for the first to rows. 

e.g. https://postimg.cc/mc8VG9c3